# magento 2 Rest api to add simple and bundle products

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, bundled-product, simple-product

I am using rest API to add simple and bundle product

Please see the below code

```
$productData = '{
  "product": {
      "sku": "TESTPRD002",
      "name": "Women`s Running - Pure Boost X Shoes",
      "attribute_set_id": 15,
      "price": 84,
      "status": 1,
      "visibility": 4,
      "type_id": "simple",
      "created_at": "2016-12-16 15:20:55",
      "updated_at": "2016-12-16 15:20:23",
      "weight": 1,
      "extension_attributes": {
        "stock_item": {
          "item_id": 1,
          "stock_id": 1,
          "qty": 20,
          "is_in_stock": true,
          "is_qty_decimal": false
        }
      },
      "product_links": [],
      "options": [],
      "tier_prices": [],
      "custom_attributes": [
        {
          "attribute_code": "description",
          "value": "<p>Lightweight and sleek, these women`s running shoes are fueled by boost™ energy. The low-profile runners blend an energy-returning boost™ midsole with a STRETCHWEB outsole for a cushioned ride with terrific ground-feel. They feature a breathable mesh upper with a sock-like fit that offers all-around support. With a full boost™ midsole that keeps every stride charged with light, fast energy, the shoe has an upper that hovers over a free-floating arch.</p>"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "short_description",
          "value": "<p>PURE BOOST X SHOES</p><p>NATURAL RUNNING SHOES WITH ARCH SUPPORT.</p>"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "meta_title",
          "value": "PURE BOOST X SHOES"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "meta_keyword",
          "value": "boost X, running, shoes, adidas"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "meta_description",
          "value": "NATURAL RUNNING SHOES WITH ARCH SUPPORT."
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "category_ids",
          "value": [
            "44"
          ]
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "url_key",
          "value": "womens-running-pure-boost-x-shoes"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "remarks",
          "value": "Lorem ipsum.."
        }
      ]
  },
  "saveOptions": true
}';
//echo $productData;
$product_url ='http://local.marketplace-release.com/marketplace/rest/V1/products/';

$setHaders = array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.$adminToken);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $product_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $productData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $setHaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

> Result : "{"message":"Unable to save product"}"

Please help me..

Comment: DONE for simple product... Now looking for Bundle...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution for a bundle, quite complicated.
It is based on Magento2 (I see different tags, but I think, according to the error message, that you want it for Magento2).

Let's assume that our bundle is identified by the SKU "bundle01" and ID *123*.

First of all, let's take some information from the product:

`GET /products/bundle01?searchCriteria`

and take note of the `"extension_attributes" --> "bundle_product_options"` section, particularly to the `option_id`fields related to your products. And take not of all the `product_links` --> `id` values related to the product.

Let's assume that we have 3 products with option_id 643, 644, 645 and id 704,705,706 respectively.

With all these information, here's the body to add a bundle product to your cart:

```
{
"cart_item": {
    "quote_id": <quote_id>,
    "sku": "bundle-01",
    "qty": 1,
    "product_option": {
    "extension_attributes": {
        "bundle_options": [{
            "option_id": 643,
            "option_qty": 1,
            "option_selections": [704]
            }, {
            "option_id": 644,
            "option_qty": 1,
            "option_selections": [705]
            }, {
            "option_id": 645,
            "option_qty": 1,
            "option_selections": [706]
            }]
        }
    }
}
}
```